# How to activage class based on anchor tag #id in URL

Tags: javascript, class, url, toggle, anchor

A while ago I noticed a page that highlighted certain areas of the page by getting the `#some_random_id` from the url.

for instance `/mypage-destination/#codex_destination_5` would obviously drop you down to the page area in question, but then highlight the area so you don't miss it.

I looked into it, and I cannot seem to find the way to extract a URL property `#` anchor destination.

Comment: You can get the value of `#` by calling `window.location.hash` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1)).style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
```

You can use window.location.hash to get the id linked in the URL(which would return #codex_destination_5 using your example). 
You can then use substring(1) to omit the hash symbol(#codex_destination_5 becomes codex_destination_5).

Using this as the id would be the next logical step.